# undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character'

Tags: compilation, makefile, fortran

I'm trying to compile someone else's fortran code and getting undefined reference errors. In particular, I get errors like this:

```
/usr/lib64/cernlib/2006/lib/libpdflib804.a(structm.o): In function `structm_':
(.text+0x17712): undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_integer'
```

My guess is that I'm not properly linking libpdflib804.a, but I do not know what I am doing wrong. Here is the makefile:

```
OBJS = hpair.o Cteq61Pdf.o mrst2001.o

LIBS = $(CERN)/libpdflib804.a $(CERN)/libpawlib.a $(CERN)/libgrafX11.a $(CERN)/libpacklib.a         $(CERN)/libmathlib.a $(CERN)/libkernlib.a

FC=f77

.f.o:
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) $*.f

hpair: $(OBJS)
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(OBJS) $(LIBS) -o run

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS)
```

My system has various those libraries in various locations (it is the cluster at CERN), but all the possible different options for $CERN give me similar errors.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what the `f77` symlink actually points to, adding `-lgfortran` or the explicit path to `libgfortran.a` when linking may help. The undefined symbol should be in this library.

Is `f77` some other compiler than gfortran? That would explain the error. The best option is to compile everything with the same compiler. Even if you manage to link code from different compilers, it may fail unexpectedly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. f77 is part of gcc. When I put `-lgfortran` in the complication, I get
`f77: -lgfortran: linker input file unused because linking not done`
and when I change the makefile `FC=gfortran` I get similar errors to before:
`/usr/lib64/cernlib/2006/lib/libmathlib.a(gauss.o): In function `gauss_':
(.text+0x2dd): undefined reference to `mtlprt_''